# SQL syntax for JSON output for polygons

Tags: json, leaflet, sql-server-2017

I have some SQL Server 2017 tables which I want to use to display points, lines & regions on maps using LeafletJS. To do this I need to store as JSON files.

The latest SQL Server has commands to do this:

For points:

```
select 'Feature' AS type, 'Point' as [geometry.type], JSON_QUERY (FORMATMESSAGE('[%s,%s]', FORMAT(WGS84Loc.Long, N'0.#####'), FORMAT(WGS84Loc.Lat, N'0.#####'))) as [geometry.coordinates], rtrim(TargetName) as [properties.name] FROM Targets FOR JSON PATH
```

For lines:

```
select 'Feature' AS type, 'LineString' as [geometry.type], JSON_QUERY (FORMATMESSAGE('[[%s,%s],[%s,%s]]', FORMAT(WGS84Loc.STPointN(1).Long, N'0.#####'), FORMAT(WGS84Loc.STPointN(1).Lat, N'0.#####'),FORMAT(WGS84Loc.STPointN(2).Long, N'0.#####'), FORMAT(WGS84Loc.STPointN(2).Lat, N'0.#####'))) as [geometry.coordinates], ID as [properties.id], rtrim(Name) as [properties.name] FROM TrailLines Where VDateTime > '2017-09-06 00:00:00' FOR JSON PATH
```

For regions/polygons:

```
select 'Feature' AS type, 'Polygon' as [geometry.type], JSON_QUERY (?????????) as [geometry.coordinates], rtrim(Name) as [properties.name] FROM Regions FOR JSON PATH
```

The first 2 work fine but the last one has me stumped. I have a standard Geography field which contains the polygon but I can't figure out the syntax for the JSON_QUERY to take the coordinates of all the vertices of the polygon & put them into a list. I figure it might have something to do with [WGS84Loc].STAsText but can't get it correct.

Would anyone know the correct SQL syntax?

Comment: is it not identical to linestring?  an array of point arrays, e.g. [[%s,%s],[%s,%s]], should be sufficient

Comment: The JSON_QUERY takes 2 parameters - first is the format and the 2nd is the actual data. For my particular linestring I know they are all single segments so I just select STPointN(1).Long, STPointN(1).Lat, STPointN(2).Long and STPointN(2).Lat.


The polygon will be more difficult as it will have a variable number of vertices. Presumably an array will be necessary but I am not sure if the SQL syntax allows me to create this array or whether I have to do it beforehand through some other method.